# How can I rewrite to my .htaccess in PHP?

Tags: php, htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How to rewrite my URL from `http://www.mysite.com/listingsecond.php?ID=1` to `http://www.mysite.com/listingsecond`?

How can I rewrite to my *.htaccess* in PHP to do this?

Comment: You can search on Google, I just found on Stack Overflow [the answer to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090104/write-a-htaccess-file-in-php).

Comment: what you want is to redirect without using .htaccess? If that is what you want, my answer may help, if that is not what you want, please clarify the question a bit.

Comment: Or are you wanting to --write to your .htaccess file using PHP??

Answer (score 0):

On your PHP file, use the $_GET variable to process the query as you need, then when generating the response, redirect to the address that you want using the [header](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function. Specifically, the location attribute